# What is the shortcut to Select Linked Flat Faces in 2.8 Beta?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, faces, selection-tools, shortcut

In 2.79 it was SHIFT CTRL ALT F

Now I can't seem to find it?

Answer (score 7):

you have to right click and assign your own in blender 2.80

[image]